# C++ Error Vector not outputting correctly

Tags: c++, vector

I'm writing a program where I just create a labs that have computers and I'm just trying to make it that there are three labs with no computers(they have empty in them). This is the following output that I'm trying to get

```
Labs:  Computer Stations: 
1:        1: empty 2: empty 3: empty
2:        1: empty 2: empty 3: empty
3:        1: empty 2: empty 3: empty
```

This is my code that I made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> labs;
    vector<string> row;
    int numrows=3;
    int rowsize=3;

    for (int i=1;i<numrows+1; i++){
        for (int j=1;j<rowsize+1; j++)
            row.push_back("empty");
        labs.push_back(row);
    }


    cout<<"labs: "<<"Computer Stations:"<<endl;




    int a=1,j=1;


    for (int i=1;i<numrows+1; i++){
        cout<<a<<":     ";
        while(j<rowsize+1){
            cout<<j<<":"<<labs[i][j];
        }
        a++;
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code I get the following output which goes on forever in a loop

```
labs: Computer Stations:
1:     1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:empty1:
```

If someone can help explaining what went wrong in my logic and why im getting weird answers and possibly a solution to help fix my error then I would be a happy c++ programmer!

Comment: you don't increase `j` in the while loop

Comment: Also, indexes in C++ start from 0, not 1.

Comment: @aslg why is that exactly? I would think it would still work since i made sure to increase numrows and rowsize by 1?

Comment: @guploo You should refrain from using extraneous variables that supposedly hold the vector's size.  Use the `vector::size()` function to tell you how many items are in the vector.  There is no need for `numrows` or `rowsize` once you have your vector's filled.

Comment: @guploo It just is (it's a feature). It's ok if you do that in the first for loop beacuse you're using `push_back` and not actually using the index (though, that's still no reason to do it, you're programming in C++ not in another language). In the other loop your index starts at 1 and ends at 3, 3 is beyond the limits of your vector because it's the **fourth** element, and you only have **three** elements.

Comment: @guploo Also, vectors (and arrays) start at 0, not 1.  Almost every attempt that I see where a coder tries to fake 1-based arrays winds up in an off-by-one error somewhere in the code -- your code is a typical case of this happening.

Comment: @aslg thank you and paul and 101010 for helping me out. I dont understand why my question got negative reviews though

Comment: @guploo Because it's a "debug my code for me" question that shows no evidence of your own troubleshooting. Also, once you 100% master C++'s zero-based indexing, you can learn how to handle it with the extra complexity of a translation layer. But why make things harder? Miss one spot (as you did) and it all breaks.

Comment: upvoted: contains MCVE , expected output, and actual output

Comment: Indeed. It's a concise question with clearly delineated input and output. If this is getting down votes, what exactly would be required to get up votes on a site devoted to helping people.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you did not increase the value of the `j` loop variable in the output loop.  The output loop could be rewritten this way:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < labs.size(); ++i)
{
   cout << i + 1 <<":     ";
   for (size_t j = 0; j < labs[i].size(); ++j)
         cout<< j + 1 << ":" <<labs[i][j];
}
```

This can also be rewritten without loo
However, there are a few things you can do to improve your code so you don't make these mistakes.

First, vectors start at index 0, not 1.  As my comment suggested, unless you have written a class that handles arrays at an offset other than 0, writing code to fake this out invariably leads to off-by-1 errors somewhere in the code base.  I know that others will say "hey, I've done it without errors", but I have come across too many cases (more than half the time) where even experienced programmers make the off-by-one mistake.

Second, this block of code:

```
vector<vector<string>> labs;
vector<string> row;
int numrows=3;
int rowsize=3;

for (int i=1;i<numrows+1; i++){
    for (int j=1;j<rowsize+1; j++)
        row.push_back("empty");
    labs.push_back(row);
}
```

can be rewritten as follows:

```
int numrows=3;
int rowsize=3;
vector<vector<string>> labs(numRows, vector<string>(rowsize,"empty"));
```

No loops.  The entire vector can be sized to the requisite number of rows and columns in one line.

Third, use `vector::size()` to tell you how many items are in the vector -- don't use extraneous variables that supposedly hold the number of items in a vector.  I have seen many cases where these unnecessary variables hold the incorrect number of items, and the programmer uses these wrong values.